# Jquery Multiselect Icon issue

Tags: jquery

How can i change icon of jquery multiselect ? by default its having 2 up and down arrows.

I would like to customize same as we customize for jquery selectbox

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize your css. If you can't find out the class for default icon, use developer tools to find out the icon. Normally the default up and down arrow icon mentioned like this-->
class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"

You can customize it in your own style by adding an external image and mention it's path to the class.